# Add new card to existing customer in Stripe Node.js

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to know how can I add a new bank card to the existing customer in Stripe using Node.js library. For example: I have a customer with Stripe customer id: cus_XXXXXXXXXX, and this customer has already 1 card and I want to add another card to the same customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer: first create a token and use that token to create a new customer with the Stripe API or update the customer with a new account number and routing number.

```
stripe.tokens.create({
    bank_account: {
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        account_holder_name:"xxxx",
        account_holder_type: "xx",
        routing_number: :"xx",
        account_number: :"xx",
    }}, function(err, token) {
        var tokenID = token.id;
        stripe.customers.createSource("cus_xxxxxxx",{
            source: tokenID
        },
        function(err, card) {}
    );
}
```

It will add a new card to the existing customer on Stripe.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [createSource](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_card) like this:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(
  // your secret key
);

stripe.customers.createSource(
  "cus_XXXXXXXXXX",
  { source: "tok_amex" },
  function(err, card) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);
```

Where `source`, is one of these:

- a *token*, like the ones returned by [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js),
- a dictionary containing user's credit card details! Like this (*not tested*):

  ```
  stripe.customers.createSource(
      "cus_XXXXXXXXXX",
      { source: {
          object: 'card',
          exp_month: ... ,//expiry month
          exp_year: ... ,//expiry year
          number: ... ,//card number
          cvc: ... // cvc of the card
      }},
      function(err, card) {
      // asynchronously called
      }
  );
  ```

Furthermore, if you wish to set the new card as the default card of the customer, you should update the [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#update_customer) object.

Comment: stripe.customers.createSource(
  "cus_XXXXXXXXXX",
  { source: "tok_amex" },
  function(err, card) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);

In this code, you use source, from where i can get the source?

Comment: @RajanMiddha I will extend my answer and elaborate on that.

Comment: i am using the following code . it thorws the error :-
"{ Error: Received unknown parameters: country, currency, account_holder_name, account_holder_type, routing_number, account_number"
stripe.customers.update(
         "cus_XXXXXXXXXX",
         { country: 'US',
            currency: 'usd',
            account_holder_name: account_holoder_name,
            account_holder_type: 'individual',
            routing_number: (router_number).toString(),
            account_number: '000444444440' },
         function(err, card) {}    );

Comment: What are you trying to update here? If you want to add a card use "source" as the update parameter. Read: [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#update_customer-source).

Comment: Solution is this :
stripe.tokens.create({
                  bank_account: {
                    country: 'US',
                    currency: 'usd',
                    account_holder_name: 'XXXXXXXX',,
                    account_holder_type: 'individual',
                    routing_number: 'XXXXXXXX',
                    account_number: 'XXXXXXXX',,
                  }
                }, function(err, token) {
   var tokenID = token.id;
                    stripe.customers.create({
                       source: tokenID
                     }, function(err, customer) {});
});

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works for me to add a card to a customer. It may help someone else out.

```
stripe.tokens.create({
    // Create the card
    card: {
      number: cardNumber,
      exp_month: expMonth,
      exp_year: expYear,
      cvc: cardCVC
    }
  }, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      // Error creating card token
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      stripe.customers.createSource(
        // Set the customer ID
        "cus_XXXXXXXX",
        // Set the source to the id of the token that was just created
        { source: token.id },
        function(err, card) {
          if (err) {
            // Error adding card to customer
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            // Success
            console.log(card)
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
```